# The ad size and ad unit ID must be set before loadAd is called from ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-activity, admob

I want to admob advertisement but i am getting java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.yavuzoktay.deprem/com.yavuzoktay.deprem.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The ad size and ad unit ID must be set before loadAd is called.

MainActivity.java

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

private BottomNavigationView navigation;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private FragmentA fragmentA = new FragmentA();
private FragmentB fragmentB = new FragmentB();
private FragmentC fragmentC = new FragmentC();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

    setTitle("Depremler");

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
    navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

    viewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()) {
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return fragmentA;
                case 1:
                    return fragmentB;
                case 2:
                    return fragmentC;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }
    });
}

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(item.getOrder());
        return true;
    }

};

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    navigation.getMenu().getItem(position).setChecked(true);
    //setTitle(String.valueOf(position));
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            setTitle("Depremler");
            break;
        case 1:
            setTitle("Büyük Depremler");
            break;
        case 2:
            setTitle("Önemli Depremler");
            break;
   }

}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

}
```

}

activity_main.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3040537334820006/3047566211">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation"/>
```

Your advice important for me

Thank you very much !

Comment: try replacing this xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  with this xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

Comment: it is working thanks

Comment: which dependency(play-services-ads) version are you using ?

Comment: you welcome @ Yavuz